# How should I compare two or more things?

Tags: adjectives

I'm wondering how you make a comparison in Esperanto

So, I mean, how do you say "The cat is more/less/equally blue than/as the dog" for example

(I don't want to just assume that it's exactly the same way English does it and look like an idiot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For equality you can use *tiel* + *kiel*.

> La kato estas tiel blua kiel la hundo.

Otherwise you can use *pli* / *malpli* + *ol*.

> La kato estas pli blua ol la hundo.
>
> La kato estas malpli blua ol la hundo.

Comment: To complete: `La kato estas plej blua.` and `La kato estas malplej blua.` (most blue / least blue.

Comment: Note that when considering precisely two things one usually uses _la pli_ instead of _la plej_: _la kato estas la pli blua_. [See PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/ceteraj/pli_plej.html#i-me3).

Answer (score 0):

Kiam vi volas montri egalecon, sen mencii adjektivon, vi povas ankaŭ uzi:

> tia ... kia

El [tekstaro.com](https://tekstaro.com/):

> Ŝi sin retrovis tia, kia ŝi ĉiam estis

Kastelo de prelongo, Valliene

> kaj sur la kolo vi havas ĉenon tian, kian ne posedas

La Faraono, Kabe

Aŭ la proverbo:

> Kia patr(in)o, tia fil(in)o

Answer (score 0):

"the cat is less/more blue than the dog" is easy: la kato estas (mal)pli blua ol la hundo

"the cat is as blue as the dog" is somewhat disputed.

Some - even some who claim that Esperanto is a language without exceptions - hold the opinion that you have to use "tiel ...kiel" (like English uses how/so for degrees...) EXCEPT where that causes confusions.

I myself belong to the school that uses "tiel/kiel" for manners and ways, and "tiom/kiom" for degrees.

"la hundo estas tiom blua kiom la kato" is clearer than "la hundo estas tiel blua kiel la kato"

the latter could be interpreted as "the dog thus is blue like the cat"